# 2 submit buttons in a single form, main submit button not submitting values

Tags: jquery

In WordPress shopping cart form, i added address search button as submit button & another "Place an order" submit button to submit all field values. both the submit buttons are in same form.

Address search function works fine if i add below. But, second submit action not working as its getting action script from plugin & themes. Cant able to save address.

In there any way we can make change input button type to work form submission or change address trigger action

Address search jquery code i used:

```
$("form.edit-address-details").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var address = $("#billing_postcode").val();     
    $.ajax({
        url:        'http://gothere.sg/maps/geo',
        dataType:   'jsonp',
        data:       {
            'output'    : 'json',
            'q'         : address,
            'client'    : '',
            'sensor'    : false
        },
        type:   'GET',
```

.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of referencing the form submit method, try capturing a form button click event:

```
$('#submit_button_1').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     ... your code...
});
$('#submit_button_2').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     ... your code...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have 2 buttons 
1. with id "addressSubmit"
2. with id "getOthers"

now change your code like below. you can also check on button label.

```
$("form.edit-address-details").submit(function(e) {
   if(e.target.id == "addressSubmit"){ // add this check here
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:        'http://gothere.sg/maps/geo',
        dataType:   'jsonp',
        data:       {
            'output'    : 'json',
            'q'         : address,
            'client'    : '',
            'sensor'    : false
        },
        type:   'POST',
   }
```

Using jquery you can also do

```
$(this).attr('value') == <BUTTON label> // instead of e.target.id
OR
$(this).attr('id') == <BUTTON ID>
```

Comment: It's advisable to not wrap objects with jQuery when you don't need to.  Attributes shouldn't be accessed this way.  Simply use `this.value` and `this.id`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Did not knew that.

Comment: Probably my most valuable jQuery knowledge has come from comments on answers I've given.  I hope I'm giving something back :)